# How to make a forum using webmatrix.

Tags: webmatrix, forum

I have an excellent idea of making a forum. And for that I have learnt some HTML, CSS and JS (what else should I learn?). While learning I found that Webmatrix is a great tool for making websites. I have made a wordpress site using webmatrix. I see it has many more options like joomla, drupal etc. Is there any option through which I can make a forum?
If yes which one should I choose?

I have already searched a lot for it but found no relevant result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to install a forum someone else has already written, or build your own from scratch?  If you're looking for an out of the box forum, I would suggest installing phpBB from the app gallery.  You can get there in WebMatrix by going New -> App Gallery -> Search for phpBB.

If you're looking to build one with ASP.NET Web Pages from scratch, I would suggest starting with the docs here:
http://www.asp.net/web-pages

A great example to follow for this path is here:
http://www.webpagescms.com/

Hope this helps.  Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks Justin, exactly what I was looking for. I also want to make an Android and Windows application for it. Which way should I go phpBB, or my own. Also should I learn PHP or ASP.NET.